# Coffeescript port client side files to node with global variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, requirejs

I use coffeescript globals like this:

```
@gameSettings = {}
```

I can assess gameSettings from any file.

In node that doesn't work anymore. Is there an easy way to port using GLOBAL so that I don't have to use requirejs / browserify (as I want the same files to still work on the client)?

Comment: AFAIK the @ symbol denotes an instance variable, and not a global. I assume it would become a global if declared in the global scope, but I think that would be a misuse

Comment: @MildFuzz  on the client @ is window and definitely not a misuse

Comment: I'm not 100% here, but I the way I saw it was that the @ in CoffeeScript is just a little syntactical sugar to tidy up `this.foo`.  In JS you generally would use the `this` keyword to attach a variable to the window, but it would work. I think the say same is true for `@`  in CoffeeScript. Not strictly a misuse, but maybe not best practise for readability.

Comment: It would be more typical to define a global object in the client with `window.gameSettings`, as that isn't context-sensitive like `@gameSettings`.

Comment: @MildFuzz also be aware that `@` can be `_this.` (the outer this) or `this.` depending on how you define the closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with `GLOBAL.gameSettings = {};`?

If you also want it to work in a browser I guess you can simply do:

```
GLOBAL = GLOBAL || window;
```

Comment: I would have to go into every file and replace @ with GLOBAL, is there no other option?

Comment: @Harry: I guess you have learn the hard lessons the hard way. And you should know what your globals are already (right?) and not have very many of them (right?) so a quick bit of grepping should sort things out.